# .png Image not showing up inside a bootstrap html tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to import two images in one of my html pages but for some reason they are not appearing. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this issue.
Here is my code and how my files are organized:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src"Icons/WebDesign.png"></img>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src"Icons/eCommerce.png"></img>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTUt.jpg

I have tried to rename and rearrange some of the files but nothing seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you checked in Web Developer tools in your browser if the image files are being downloaded correctly?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you'r missing `=` sign while setting the attribute `src`, the correct snippet would look like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="Icons/WebDesign.png"></img>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img src="Icons/eCommerce.png"></img>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I kinda feel stupid after looking at it and seeing that I missed something like that but thanks for you help. I greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

( **NOTE:** try to debug your code, what error you get. )

Now try this:

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="Icons/WebDesign.png" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>Hello</p>
   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="Icons/eCommerce.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    <p>Hello</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it worked after I put the equal sign after src. Thanks a lot for your help. I greatly appreciate it :)